# How to trigger Cordova/PhoneGap In App Browser

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I want to use the [In App Browser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) that comes with the latest version of Cordova. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to set it up with my Xcode.

Ive added the example code to my html file:

```
// Wait for Cordova to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
     var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
     ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
     ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
     ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });
}
```

But I am unsure on how to trigger it when a button is tapped:

```
<a href="#">Click Me</a>
```

Would anyone know how to properly set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I messed around with JQueries click() function and seem to have gotten it working:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $('#apache').click(function() {
        var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
        ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
        ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
        ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });
    });
</script>

<a href="#" id="apache">Apache</a>
```

I realized the default example triggers on a new window/page open event.

Please note if you are using JQuery Mobile as I am the above code needs to go under your `data-role="page"` containing div.